# Why %v is printing unexpected value for nested struct?

Tags: go

When printing a struct with nested struct which has a String() implemented, the `%v` format prints an 'unexpected' value per our understanding.

Below is the code snippet.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Inner struct {
}

type A struct {
    Inner
    FieldA string
}

func (i Inner) String() string {
    return "anything"
}

func main() {
    myA := A{FieldA: "A"}
    fmt.Printf("%v", myA)
}
```

We expect the output to be

> {anything A}

But the actual result is

> anything

Why this result? It seems `FieldA` is ignored? To make it more confusing, if we have two nested structs where both of them have String() implemented, the output is expected.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type Inner struct {
}

type InnerAgain struct {
}

type A struct {
    Inner
    InnerAgain
    FieldA string
}

func (i Inner) String() string {
    return "anything"
}

func (i InnerAgain) String() string {
    return "nothing"
}

func main() {
    myA := A{FieldA: "A"}
    fmt.Printf("%v", myA)
}
```

The output is

> {anything nothing A}

...

Comment: shouldn't Inner be Inner string?

Comment: @Pizzalord: no, because it's an embedded field of type `Inner`, not a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are embedding `Inner`, you inherent all its properties - including the String() - function. So `%v` is actually calling `Inner.String()`

From the docs (https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) :

> 5. If an operand implements method `String() string`, that method will
>      be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be
>      formatted as required by the verb (if any).

Comment: And to expand, if you have two embedded structs, both of which have a String() function, then calling `String()` on the embedding struct is ambiguous, and thus those those String() methods are not promoted.  This causes the embedding struct (`A`) to no longer implement the `fmt.Stringer` interface, so `fmt` falls back to the default printing format, which is why you get the full structure in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `fmt` package states the rules for `%v` as:

> If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:
>
> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

Hence, `%v` actually uses the `String()` method for arguments that are stringers.